# Workbench freezes on connecting after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and started having this issue, I can connect to my local mysql server via the terminal fine using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

however when I try to use mysql workbench it just gets stuck on connecting and wb.log displays the following:

```
11:39:07 [INF][   WBContext UI]: Initializing workbench context UI with these values:
    base dir: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    plugin path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/plugins
    struct path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt
    module path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules
    library path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries
    user data dir: /home/<REPLACED USERNAME>/.mysql/workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No
11:39:07 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
11:39:08 [INF][            WBA]: Looking for extension modules for WBA...
11:39:08 [INF][            WBA]: 0 extension modules found
11:39:08 [WRN][            grt]: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml:1401: link 'om.mysql.rdbms.mysql.driver.native_sshtun' <object > key=owner could not be resolved
11:39:08 [WRN][            grt]: /home/<REPLACED USERNAME>/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml:27: link '6d8ecd74-acad-11e8-9c35-408d5cdbf11f' <object GrtObject> key=owner could not be resolved
11:39:08 [INF][      WBContext]: System info:
    MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 8.0.12 CE build 13312926 (64 bit)
    Configuration Directory: /home/<REPLACED USERNAME>/.mysql/workbench
    Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    Cairo Version: 1.15.10
    OS: Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64
    CPU: 8x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v5 @ 3.40GHz (3700.971MHz) - 15.62GiB RAM
No video adapter info available
    Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

    Fips mode enabled: no

11:39:08 [INF][    WQE backend]: Found auto-save workspace /home/<REPLACED USERNAME>/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/local-1.autosave
11:39:09 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Opened connection 'local' to (Ubuntu) version 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

When I edit the connection in mysql workbench and click "Test Connection" i get the following result:

[image: mysql-test-connection]

So here is a few things I have tried so far:

1. Completely purged mysql-server, mysql-commons, mysql-client etc.
2. Reinstalled mysql-server
3. Logged into the mysql server via terminal and modified the plugin for root user to use mysql_native_password
4. Tried creating a new custom user and tried logging into that, once again it works via terminal but not via MySQL Workbench.
5. Ran apt update, apt upgrade
6. Downloaded latest MySQL Workbench from their website and installed that.

It wouldn't even allow me to connect to a fresh db install after mysql server reinstall.

These are the versions I'm working on:
MYSQL Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Linux Kernel Version: 4.15.0-33-generic
Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
MYSQL Client Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I managed to resolve this issue, it seems that after the upgrade my settings must've got screwed up. The connection that wasn't even the one I was attempting to use which was a bit strange.

I went into the paths that mentioned in the log:

```
11:39:08 [WRN][            grt]: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml:1401: link 'om.mysql.rdbms.mysql.driver.native_sshtun' <object > key=owner could not be resolved
11:39:08 [WRN][            grt]: /home/<REPLACED USERNAME>/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml:27: link '6d8ecd74-acad-11e8-9c35-408d5cdbf11f' <object GrtObject> key=owner could not be resolved
```

And deleted the 'value' tags as well as the connection that was throwing the error and restarted mysql workbench. After the restart some of the connections I had setup were gone (which I can just recreate) but it seems that I can connect fine now.